# Issue with running Vagrant in Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, composer-php, homestead

I tried setting up a virtual machine using Homestead box. I followed documentation on Laravel site for setting up Homestead.

When I ran the command `vagrant up`, it seemed to work in setting a VM. Then it asked to run `vagrant provision`, which I did.

I can't get pass red text 'You are already using composer version 1.1.3 (stable channel)'. I don't know what to do next.

[image]

Update: here is Homestead.yaml file:

[image]

Comment: your vm seems to boot fine, did you actually tried ssh'ing in with "homestead ssh" in ~/Homestead directory?

Comment: do yo mean running `homestead ssh` in the terminal from ~/Homestead? If so, I did that and got `homestead: command not found`

Comment: whoops my bad, i mean "vagrant ssh" sry, you need to register that "homestead" cmd for running from anywhere, its on homestead doc

Comment: `vagrant ssh` is working. What should I do next to see my laravel/lumen site up and running? I already set up Homestead.yaml, but got `No input file specified.` when I open the URL. Let me add another screenshot, so it is more clear for you. Thanks.

Comment: post your Homestead.yaml file?

Comment: pls see my update.

Comment: did you actually install lumen yet?

Comment: No. should I run this `composer global require "laravel/lumen-installer` to install? But the folders are not mapping, with or without Lumen installation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116541/discussion-between-prashank-and-rattanak).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to edit the file at

```
~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml
```

instead of

```
~/Homestead/Homestead.yaml
```

after that reload it as usual

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

Comment: not sure why there need to be two versions of Homestead.yaml, since only one is needed. (Windows version).

Comment: the one in ~/Homestead is like a template that is copied to ~/.homestead when you run init.bat on windows and init.sh on *unix

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
~/.composer/vendor/bin
```

to Your PATH on host machine (not inside vm).

After restart terminal You can use `homestead` command.

Comment: I doubt he has composer installed on host machine, also the correct approach for "global" homestead is https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead#daily-usage

Comment: I uninstalled Composer already, it is not needed on the host since Composer is included in Homestead box.