# Composer getting Stuck when generating autoload files

Tags: php, composer-php

I am using composer with Windows, and it was working great, but this week, the composer just gets stuck on the update, it just get stuck at any final task.

For example:

When updating: it get stuck in the `"Generating autoload files"` message.

When self-updating: it get stuck in the `"You are already using composer version 1.4.1 (stable channel)"`.

I tried older Versions of composer, but they all get stuck at the end.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38218034/issue-with-running-vagrant-in-homestead) question. Might be similar issue.

Comment: The problem is that i use Windows 10.

Comment: have you tried the verbose flag? (```composer -v ...```). It should yeld more information which could led you to solve your problem.

Comment: Some troubleshooting hints: Isolate the problem to tell update (or install etc.) to not dump the autoloader. Then replay the issue with `composer dump-autoload`, add verbosity etc. If the autoload generation scans for classes (`classmap`), both recursive file traversal is involved as well as running regular expressions on file contents. This can be extensive (and probably get stuck). then backup the vendor folder and remove subtrees to locate if a certain file is causing this (if you don't have ability to monitor the autoload run with strace etc.).

Answer (score -1):

Change the timeout expiration. You can change the value in your Composer configuration or the environment, to just name two.

From the [Composer configuration](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#config):

> **process-timeout**
>
> The timeout in seconds for process executions, defaults to 300 (5mins). The duration processes like git clones can run before Composer assumes they died out. You may need to make this higher if you have a slow connection or huge vendors. [...] *[[ref](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#process-timeout)]*

From the [Composer environment](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#environment-variables):

> **COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT**
>
> This env[ironment] var[iable] controls the time Composer waits for commands (such as git commands) to finish executing. The default value is 300 seconds (5 minutes). *[[ref](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-process-timeout)]*

For example, I use this environment variable in a container environment.

Comment: As this may be useful for timeout problems, the question is clearly not about timeout problems as composer would tell when running into a timeout with a message after the one reported in question. More a comment than an answer?

Comment: The question is about composer stuck at generating optimized files. Timeout is not the problem.